# How to put subtitles in mobile videos with Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie in unity

Tags: android, video, fullscreen, unity-game-engine, subtitle

So i'm making an unity project for mobile device ( android ) and i ran into the problem of playing videos through unity in mobile devices witch can only be achieved trough `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` or Assets.

So, in `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` the video goes full screen and everything goes behind it and since i want it to have support for some languages(if i have to include 3 copies of the same video the game will start getting to big ;-;). My doubt is , is it possible to put a subtitle in it without creating another video?

Comment: I recommend downloading the corresponding video from internet, that way your app won't be to heavy!

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios That's exactly what i ended up doing, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

There is a logic solution to this. You can you [GUI.Label](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) to print anything on the Screen.

You use a timer / counter to print relevant text on the Screen at the right time.

Create a rectangle at the position where you want to display the text

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Hello World!");
```

Comment: This is not possible, since the Unity core is paused when you are using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie, please try to test your "logic solution" before posting an "answer"